# Are All sins forgivable if one asks forgiveness before death and dosen't repeat those sins

Tags: allah, sin, forgiveness, tawba, masturbation

Salam i want to know that there are major sins and minor sins in Islam so if some one commits major sins because minor sins are forgiven with tawbah but if someone does limited major sins, minor shirk, masturbation,pornography, smoking,drinking are they forgivable if the person who commits them asks for Allah's forgiveness before death and promises not to repeat those sins again and changes is there a chance for his forgivenessto be accepted?,please reply it will be helpfull

Comment: Yes you will be forgiven.

Comment: Even for masturbation?

Comment: What part of my answer did you not understand? Yes you will be forgiven for anything that you do.

Comment: Thank you brother/sister may Allah have mercy on us all say ameen❤

Comment: Every sin will be forgiven with the given criteria in question but what we do to people. We should make up for what we do to them and then our sin will be forgiven

Comment: Thanks you brother/sister

Answer (score 0):

In the Qur'an, God says to the Prophet: Say [that Allah declares,] ‘O My servants who have committed excesses against their own souls, do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed Allah will forgive all sins. Indeed, He is the All-forgiving, the All-merciful.39_v53.
Moreover, your Lord will indeed be forgiving and merciful to those who repent after they having committed evil out of ignorance and reform themselves.16_v119
do not worry about God's forgiveness. He forgives. The first sign of accepting his repentance is to see that he will no longer commit those great sins. This means that his repentance is real.

The method of repentance from the sins that are the right of God is real repentance and the intention to leave permanently and not to repeat it, and in cases where an obligatory act has been abandoned, make up for that obligatory act; Such as performing the prayers that he has not prayed and the fasts that he has not fasted, etc., and in the case of sins that are the right of the people, in addition to repentance and remorse, he must fulfill the right of the people, unless the rightful one overrides his right and makes it lawful.
That is, if someone's right is lost or someone's reputation is lost, or if someone or a group has deviated from the right path because of his propaganda, he should. Let them know.